# Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "id", target is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, javascript-objects

I'm trying to let users switch website theme by switching theme.css stylesheets with JS DOM and then saving the selected theme to cookies for a later website visit.
I tried following [a tutorial by Larry Ullman about 'Modern Javascript'](https://larryullman.com/books/modern-javascript-develop-and-design/) but I fear that the tutorial I am following is outdated and therefore does not work too well in newer times.
**[The error I get with Firefox Developer Edition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/cant_access_property):**

```
Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "id", target is undefined
    setThemeCookie http://127.0.0.1:5500/js/index.js:52
    onload http://127.0.0.1:5500/js/index.js:68
```

**And here's my code:**

Index.js:

```
function setTheme(theme) {  
  var css = null;
  if (document.getElementById('cssTheme')) {
    css = document.getElementById('cssTheme');
    css.href = 'css/' + theme + '.css';
  }else{
    css = document.createElement('link');
    css.rel = 'stylesheet';
    css.href = 'css/' + theme + '.css';
    css.id = 'cssTheme';
    document.head.appendChild(css);
  }
};

// make cookie when themeButton clicked
function setThemeCookie(e) {
  if (typeof e == 'undefined') e = window.event;

  if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault();
  } else {
    e.returnValue = false;
  }

  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;

  // bake cookie
  var expire = new Date();
  expire.setDate(expire.getDate() + 7);
  COOKIE.setCookie('theme', target.id, expire);

  // update cookie recipe
  setTheme(target.id);
  return false;
}

// Use saved theme on window load:
window.onload = function () {
  document.getElementById('darkTheme').onclick = setThemeCookie;
  document.getElementById('lightTheme').onclick = setThemeCookie;
  document.getElementById('sdarkTheme').onclick = setThemeCookie;
  document.getElementById('slightTheme').onclick = setThemeCookie;

  var theme = COOKIE.getCookie('theme');
  if (theme) {
    setThemeCookie(theme);
  }
};
```

relevant parts of index.html:

```
<!--head-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/darkTheme.css" id="cssTheme">
<script defer src="js/index.js"></script>
<script defer src="js/cookie.js"></script>

<!--body-->
<abbr title="dark"><button id="darkTheme"></button></abbr>
<abbr title="light"><button id="lightTheme"></button></abbr>
<abbr title="solarized dark"><button id="sdarkTheme"></button></abbr>
<abbr title="solarized light"><button id="slightTheme"></button></abbr>
```

darkTheme.css as a visualization of what a theme.css file looks like:

```
:root{
  --text-1: #ddd;
  --text-2: #aaa;
  --text-3: #777;
  --bg-0: #101010;
  --bg-1: #111;
  --bg-2: #181818;
  --bg-3: #202020;
}
#footer-logo{
  filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
}
```

I suspect the issue with target.id is never specified, and even if e.id or css.id was, it would be unable to retrieve the .id value from target.id (if that makes sense). I'm also pretty new to the JavaScript language, so I might not understand the obvious. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure there is `darkTheme`, `lightTheme` ... in the index.html body ?

Comment: @Core972 I have changed the question to show the body element buttons and their id's

Comment: Tried to create in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/zje5g9vf/) and everything works fine

Comment: You would try to call getAttribute method for element.

Comment: @faxterol Hey, thanks. But I'm not sure how to do that. Will you provide an example or a snippet of what you mean please?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
const div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
const align = div1.getAttribute('align');

alert(align); // Shows the value of align for the element with id="div1"
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute